# How to remove outdoor drain cover to clean insides and prevent overflow?

Tags: drain, tools, cover, removal

[image: Drain grille cover]

I want to know what tools I need to remove this drain cover. The insides are starting to get clogged and I'm afraid of overflow.

Can I remove without sawing it off?

Comment: What size is that cover?  Can't really tell scale from that image.  Also, what material is it?

Comment: One average male footlength squared.

Comment: There's no rust so can't be iron. Steel? But it isn't shiny enough. Copper? Don't know. bronze? aluminum?

Comment: It's vanishingly unlikely to be stainless steel (too expensive).  Otherwise, the only difference between "iron" and "steel" is how carefully the carbon content is controlled - (wrought iron can be practically carbon free, cast iron is saturated, steel is in between).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either stick a screwdriver/crowbar in the gap round the edge and lever it up, or just stick a crowbar into the grillwork and lever.  Be careful with the second option though - if it's fixed in hard, you might snap the grill.

Check the small holes at the top and bottom of the picture - they *might* contain some sort of bolt which needs to be unscrewed with (eg) an Allan Key.

Comment: Agree - large metal grates are usually held in place with gravity alone.  There's a lot of junk in the cracks around the edges now, so it might be hard to remove.